# Is it possible to take a static snapshot of a website to "replay" that page locally for performance testing?

Tags: performance, google-chrome

I am working on a complex web app where I'm tasked with improving the TTI performance of the home page across various build configuration variations - specifically looking at JavaScript performance.

It's not trivial to switch between variants and I can only access it over a VPN using the full staging environment.

To decrease the feedback loop, I would like to download a static clone of this web app so I can work on it from my local machine without interference.

Using Chrome's "save as" function to save the website does not work as it doesn't pull dynamically loaded javascript assets and doesn't mock the HTTP responses.

Is there an easy way to download a website in a way that lets you supply the assets, mock any http requests and essentially "replay" the page in isolation?

I had considered manually stubbing the backend by writing a proxy service that lazily caches the back end requests, offering replayability.